# eldoc mode hangs emacs when fetching information to show in echo

Tags: debugging, emacs, haskell-mode

I am fairly new to emacs and have been using Haskell mode and writing `.hs` scripts in emacs. I have noticed that it freezes whilst fetching information to show in the echo bar.

Disabling `global-eldoc-mode` seems to fix this. I am sure this is not a problem everyone faces and I would like to be able to keep `eldoc` enabled since I appreciate all the help recently having picked up Haskell. Any ideas of how to approach this problem?

I am running `emacs 26.2` and am running Haskell mode from downloaded from `melpa.org`.

I would appreciate any comments/ help,
Thanks

Comment: I think I'm getting the same problem as you. When running emacs in a GUI it freezes where I cannot use the keyboard, but still can use the mouse. I run my emacs as a server so I tried connecting through the terminal with emacsclient -nw and it worked still. Maybe as a temp work around you could use emacsclient -nw. If I try killall -SIGUSR2 emacs whilst it's having this problem then I get 'eldoc-pre-command-refresh-echo-area' listed in the backtrace

Comment: Have you tried 26.2.90? How do you re-enact the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I haven’t tried 26.2.90. I re-enact the problem whenever I open emacs because I haven’t disable eldoc mode in my config file. So whilst I’m typing a function out and I use a primitive it will just hang whilst it’s grabbing the information to tell me what the type signature of the primitive is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a late answer, but I had the same issue, and after some trial and error I figured it out: simply turn off  the "Haskell Doc Prettify Types" setting. Probably some sort of issue with Unicode characters.